# Qual è il significato di "stranito" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Si divertiva a disegnare macchine impossibili alla Munari, ibridi di animali mitologici, come il gufo **stranito** che sta sulla copertina di *L'altrui mestiere*, il libro in cui aveva raccolto le sue divagazioni di "dilettante curioso e libertino", le invasioni in campi altrui.

Il soggetto di questa frase è Primo Levi e la copertina a cui fa riferimento penso sia [questa](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-eVtNt5QDnIk/U016H_XLw1I/AAAAAAAAC34/k4_xN9xnA_g/s1600/scansione0001.jpg). Non riesco a capire il senso di "stranito" in questo brano. Nei dizionari ho trovato che può significare "inquieto", "nervoso", "intontito". Tuttavia, guardando la copertina, non mi è chiaro che questo sia il significato adatto al contesto. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: A me sembra che il senso sia questo, in una delle sue sfumature. L'espressione di quel gufo si può considerare un po' perplessa o nervosa (guarda di fianco, come se temesse l'arrivo di qualcuno, per esempio).

Comment: La copertina della prima edizione si vede in questa scheda: http://www.primolevi.it/Web/Italiano/Contenuti/Opera/110_Edizioni_italiane/L%27altrui_mestiere. Il gufo è colto in tre momenti, tre espressioni. Per il senso, concordo con @DaG. Tieni conto che "stranito" indica uno stato d'animo che ti porta a non stare bene ma senza saper capire e spiegare perché.

Comment: Mi hai convinta, @Benedetta! Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: Ci provo, @Charo.

Comment: Se @DaG volesse poi verificarla, ne sarei contenta.

Comment: Mi sembra che vada benissimo, @Benedetta. Poi va' a sapere quale specifica sfumatura avesse in mente Ferrero.

Comment: Chissà, @DaG...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La copertina della prima edizione si vede in questa scheda: http://www.primolevi.it/Web/Italiano/Contenuti/Opera/110_Edizioni_italiane/L%27altrui_mestiere. Il gufo è colto in tre momenti, tre espressioni.

Per il senso, va considerato che "stranito" indica uno stato d'animo che porta a non stare bene, ma senza saper capire e spiegare perché.